# what is domain class in Entity Data Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am newbie to Entity Data Framework.I want to know what is Domain Class. I googled this problem a lot but couldn't find the appropriate solution for it.

Comment: Also, please take a look in the help center to see how to ask on-topic questions here.

Answer (score 2):

You question is quite vague, but:

A domain object is often your entity class. For example, "Users" would be considered domain objects as they are a core element to the over all domain model. The domain model being a representation of all the key elements to your problem/system

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model